# how to compile Ignite application on CMake?

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, ignite, java-11, gcc5

I did compile Ignite Application successfully.
but The Binary didn't work.

`/tmp/tmp.Nw0IPD6ru3/cmake-build-debug-local-container/planet_engine: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

how can I make to it work?

Also, I compiled C++ Examples successfully. such as ignite-compute-example.
and, I execute that but I got an error message.
`An error occurred: JVM library is not found (did you set JAVA_HOME environment variable?)`

and I using a nightly release version `2.8.0.20190213` because I couldn't build to version 2.7 in my environment.

I posted environment values down.

```
IGNITE_HOME=
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash 
LIBRARY_PATH=/root/jre1.8.0_201/lib/amd64/server:/root/jre1.8.0_201/lib/amd64/
LC_NUMERIC=ko_KR.UTF-8
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
JRE_HOME=/root/jre1.8.0_201
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:d...
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/root/jre1.8.0_201/lib/amd64/server:/root/jre1.8.0_201/lib/amd64/
CLASS_PATH=/root/jdk-11.0.2/lib:
LC_TELEPHONE=ko_KR.UTF-8
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/jdk-11.0.2/bin
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ko_KR.UTF-8 
JAVA_HOME=/root/jdk-11.0.2
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ko_KR.UTF-8
JDK_HOME=/root/jdk-11.0.2/lib
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root 
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LC_TIME=ko_KR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ko_KR.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Thank you for reading. :)

Comment: `JAVA_HOME=/root/jdk-11.0.2` WTF? Are you doing everything as root?

Comment: @melpomene There is in docker container.. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

I am working on a docker container environment.

and therefore I am using remote build and debug with ssh and gdb.

finally, I found out why it couldn't find `libjvm.so` and why couldn't read environment values such as `JAVA_HOME`.

because it is working in gdb for now.

I confirmed that it is working when without gdb.

I will find a solution.
and, if I have been found, I will update the answer.

---

[Solved]

I share how I make solved that.

I was using an Oracle JDK-11 through source install.

but Ignite C++ client need something different with latest released jdk versions.

Ignite need a directory structure like this

```
JAVA_HOME/ (as JDK install directory)
  - jre/
    - lib/
  - lib/
  ...
```

I solved by `apt install openjdk-8-jdk`.
openjdk-8-jdk have structure for what Ignite need.

i added JAVA_HOME, IGNITE_HOME, at `/etc/environment`.

It works finally.

but I got another problem. HAHA 
I am so sad.

This also GDB problem..

Comment: Can you share it or at least some clues?